# Rails 4 - Rolify - expiry date on role instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am trying to figure out how to use rolify in my Rails 4 app.

I have a users table and a roles table.

The roles table has the following:

```
create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", using: :btree
```

I also have a user_roles join table with ids for each of user and role ids.

I want to create some roles which have limited durations (the user's time in that role is limited rather than the role itself). If I appoint someone as a student, I will know their expected graduation date, so I can appoint them in the role student until around the graduation date. I want to add a renew function to allow them to continue beyond that date if I check to confirm that it is appropriate.

I'm not sure whether to add an expiry date date attribute and a boolean renew? attribute on my roles model, or if there is a better way of approaching this. Does anyone have any ideas that might help?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach, though I'm not sure you need the renew boolean unless you think you'll use it regularly. When the expiry date is reached, it could trigger an action that lets you reset the expiry date. Of course having the renew boolean would mean the renewal could be automated.

Comment: I get very confused in thinking about this. Isn't the role class where the actual roles themselves are stored. So an expiry date would be an expiry for the role itself (rather than the user that has been assigned that role?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rollify gem, will it let you add an expiry attribute to the class? You may need to add it to the user, then delete that role when the expiry date is reached.